# Unable to add '[]' to @Query name. Tried multiple ways

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

I am using `@nestjs/swagger` for API documentation. I want my queryParam to be `features[]` and not `features` when swagger makes the request.
Nest searches for `@Query` in route handlers and documents automatically.

> The SwaggerModule searches for all @Body(), @Query(), and @Param() decorators in route handlers to generate the API document. It also creates corresponding model definitions by taking advantage of reflection.
> [from here](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters)

So if my variable name is `features` in code, documentation automatically picks that up. The request fails because `features` is not an array for a single element. If I try to separately add the param to the swagger document using `@ApiQuery`, I have the option to name the param `features[]` but it shows up separately, and I am unable to remove the automatically added `features` param.

```
@Get('/:uuid/configs')
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Get configs for user',
  })

  //manually add param with [] in the name
  @ApiQuery({
    name: 'features[]',
    required: true,
    type: [String],
  })

  async getUserConfigs(
    //automatic pickup from here
    @Query() queryParams: GetUserConfigQueryParamsDto,
  ) {

    return {
      success: true,
    } as ResponseBuilder;
  }
```

[image: image1]

I also tried to pass the name of the query as I want as a parameter in @Query.

```
@Get('/:uuid/configs')
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Get configs for user',
  })

  //manually add param with [] in the name
  @ApiQuery({
    name: 'features[]',
    required: true,
    type: [String],
  })

  async getUserConfigs(
    //Added the desired name as a param
    @Query('features[]') queryParams: GetUserConfigQueryParamsDto,
  ) {

    return {
      success: true,
    } as ResponseBuilder;
  }
```

This changes the name in swagger for sure. But when I execute the request in this case, the `[` converts to `%5B` and `%5D` due to encoding. So the request fails.

I want only `features[]` and not both. But I can not remove @Query or add [] to the variable name. How do I get only `features[]`?

Here is the `GetUserConfigQueryParamsDto` jic:

```
export class GetUserConfigQueryParamsDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsArray()
  @ArrayNotEmpty()
  features: string[];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GetUserConfigQueryParamsDto` class at `@ApiProperty()` decorator above features add name like this

`@ApiProperty({ name: 'features[]'})`